# Main class instance for all subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I got three classes: `Bank`, `account` and `Coin`. I want the class `Bank` to have a default coin variable , which I pass on to its constructor. So I extended account to `Bank,` this would mean that I can access the default coin variable through the method `getmainCoin()` via the `account` class. For some reason I'm getting this error when trying that:

> Error:(12, 32) java: constructor bank in class com.company.bank cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: com.company.Coin
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
// Instantiations 
Coin dollars = new Coin("Dollar", "$");;
bank SomeBank = new bank(dollars);
Person john = new Person("John Doe", 20, dollars, new account(9058));
System.out.println(john.checkbalance());

public class bank {
  public String name;
  private int coinsheld;
  private Coin maincoin;

  public bank(Coin maincoin){
      this.maincoin = maincoin;
  }

  public Coin getmainCoin(){
      return this.maincoin;
  }

}

public class account extends bank {
  private int balance;
  private static int accounts;
  private int accnumber;
  private Coin coin;

  public account(int balance){
      this.balance = balance;
      this.accounts += 1;
      this.accnumber = accounts;
      this.coin = getmainCoin();
  }
}

public class Coin {
  public static int total;
  private String name;
  private String sign;
  private int id;

  public Coin(String name, String sign){
      this.name = name;
      this.sign = sign;
      this.id = total + 1;
  }

  public int getID(){
      return this.id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you getCoin() in your "Account" object there is no coin set in that given object, lets review it step by step:

- There is an Bank class
- Account class extends bank (BUT DOESNT set the coin attribute/variable because you dont set it in constructor neither with a setCoint() method)
- You use getMainCoin()->coin value was never set->Error:"com.company.Coin found".

So you can take this approaches:

1. If you want to set the default coin to ALL the Bank objects you can do a class variable (also called static variable) changing "private Coin maincoin;" to "private static Coin maincoin". If you take this approach you should create a static method "setCoin()" or make your constructor static.

   That way if you extend that class, and once a Coin object has been set to the Bank class, every object of that class (or that extends it, for instance) will have the same Coin Object.
2. But if you want each Bank object to have a different default Coin (even the new Account objects you create) then you sould add to your Account constructor a parameter to set the coin or a setCoint() method and not calling getCoin() before you even set if, of course.

EDITED: because of typos and visual appeal.

Comment: I thought by extending a class, the subclass inherits the superclass'  variables and methods passed on by its constructor

Comment: if it is a class variable (static) yes, but if not, now you got a BRAND NEW object of your BANK class (which happens to be an Account object), and you havent set the coin variable in. As LLL answered (and as stated in my second point of the ordered list) you can use "super(coin)" to set the coin variable in this BRAND NEW object by calling this Bank constructor. However you must get the coin value fro soewhere and as stated there, I suggets you get if from the Account constructor.

Comment: What's not really clear is your second point though: "Account class extends bank (BUT DOESNT set the coin attribute/variable because you dont set it in constructor neither with a setCoint() method)" , as far as I can see it states in the bank constructor this.maincoin = maincoin. And then I made a new bank instance "bank SomeBank = new bank(dollars);", which passes dollars as maincoin, so it has to be set?

Answer (score 0):

In your account class you must call bank constructor because account extends bank and there is no default (no argument) constructor.
Do something like this:

```
super(coin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `account` class constructor which is `public account(int balance)` implicitly **calls the parent class default constructor** i.e., `super();`, but you did not provide any default constructor in your `bank` class.

So, you can solve the issue by creating a default constructor in your `bank` class as shown below:

```
public class bank {

    public bank() {
    }

   //your code here
}
```

However, **your class relationships are not correct i.e., when you say `Account extends Bank` in java, it means that `Account` IS-A `Bank`, which doesn't seem right.**

Also, you are NOT following java naming conventions for Class, method, variable names i.e., Class/Interface names starts with Upper case where as method/variable names should be lower case.

Comment: So I'm forced to make a method in bank class "setMaincoin(Coin somecoin){}" and need to set it?

Comment: no, you need to add a default constructor in `bank` class like shown above

Comment: Okay, but how else would I set a coin as the main coin for al subclasses of bank? Since it's not passed on in the constructor of bank.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you **extend a class**, the **sub-class** automatically calls `super()`, in its constructor. `super()` basically calls the **super-class**' constructor. Now, your **super-class** `bank` doesn't have a *argument-less constructor*, because you **overrode the default one**. To fix, do add a constructor like this:-

```
public bank() {

}
```

Or you could explicitly call `super` with a `Coin` object.

```
public account(int balance){
  super(someCoinReference);
  ..//rest of code
}
```

However, this is probably not what you want.